# In Power BI X-axis label, how to show only week starting day instead of all date series?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

Without grouping date values we need to customize x-axis label values week starting day. One more condition is we need to show all the value points in a week.

**Right now my chart is**

[image]

**And what we need is**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following calculated column in the query editor `Edit Queries > Add Column > Custom Column`:

[image]

Drag and drop the custom column into your visual and you are done. Don´t forget to change the type of the column to date format.

Comment: No it not help me, actually it group the values to week starting day, without grouping we need to customize label values has week starting day :( @Strawberryshrub

Comment: This is not possible in Power BI, you can´t customize the labels (like in SSRS for example). This what I posted, would be the only work around. Maybe in the future they will implement it.